# Get the last column letter in Excel in a specific row that has data

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

If I have data in row 4 in columns A through F, and I want to know that F is the last column with data, what formula can I put in B2 to get an answer of F?

Comment: You can get the column number with MATCH(); `=MAX(IFERROR(MATCH(1e+99,A4:F4),0),IFERROR(MATCH("ZZZ",A4:F4),0))`

Comment: Is the Column the end result or are you going to use that for something else?

Comment: You can freely edit your own posts but for your protection, this must be done under the original user account.  It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer.  See [Merge my accounts](http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) to get your accounts merged, which will solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the column number with the following:

```
=MAX(IFERROR(MATCH(1e+99,A4:F4),0),IFERROR(MATCH("ZZZ",A4:F4),0))
```

Then if you need the actual letter then:

```
=CHOOSE(MAX(IFERROR(MATCH(1e+99,A4:F4),0),IFERROR(MATCH("ZZZ",A4:F4),0)),"A","B","C","D","E","F")
```

If what is wanted is the last value in that range then:

```
=INDEX(A4:F4,MAX(IFERROR(MATCH(1e+99,A4:F4),0),IFERROR(MATCH("ZZZ",A4:F4),0)))
```

The last two will give errant information if there is no data in the row.

Answer (score 0):

To return the column letter of the last cell in row 4 that contains data:

```
=LEFT(ADDRESS(1,LOOKUP(2,1/(LEN($4:$4)>0),COLUMN($4:$4)),2),FIND("$",ADDRESS(1,LOOKUP(2,1/(LEN(4:4)>0),COLUMN($4:$4)),2))-1)
```

- The `LOOKUP` function returns the column number of the last data containing column.
- The `ADDRESS` function converts that to an A1 style address with relative column addressing.
- The `FIND` function finds the `$` which, due to the address type, will immediately follow the Column Letter.
- The `LEFT` function then uses the result of the `FIND` to return the appropriate column letter.

If you want the contents of the last cell in row 4 that contains data, then try:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(LEN($4:$4)>0),$4:$4)
```